# Why PHP strlen() and Javascript xxx.length is not equal?

Tags: javascript, php

I have following text:

> Ankylosaurus was an armored dinosaur that lived roughly 67 million
>   years ago, at the very end of the Cretaceous Period. This genus was
>   among the last of the non-avian dinosaurs, living alongside
>   Tyrannosaurus, Triceratops, and Edmontosaurus. Its name means 'fused
>   lizard'; bones in its skull and other parts of its body were fused,
>   increasing their strength. Ankylosaurus was up to 6.25 m (20.5 feet)
>   long and 1.7 m (5.6 feet) tall, weighing about 4.8–8 tonnes
>   (11,000–18,000 lb). It had a broad, robust body with a wide, low
>   skull. The front parts of the jaws were covered in a beak, with rows
>   of small, leaf-shaped teeth behind it, adapted for a herbivorous diet.
>   It was covered in armor plates for protection against predators, with
>   bony half-rings covering the neck, and had a large club on the end of
>   its tail which may have been used as a weapon. Fossils from a few
>   specimens of Ankylosaurus have been found in various geological
>   formations in western North America, but a complete skeleton has

Now I run bellow PHP and JS code:

```
echo strlen(trim($text));
```

and

```
var text = "above text";
alert( text.length);
```

Now PHP is showing 1004 and JS is showing me 1000 characters, Why?

Comment: Not sure if it's the issue here but JavaScript won't operate on raw bytes unless you use certain specific data types like Node.js `Buffer` (not plain strings).

Comment: In PHP you use `trim()` if there are any extra chars on the end it will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using not the normal dash within following lines `4.8–8 tonnes (11,000–18,000 lb)`. This character uses 3 bytes (you used it twice, so it's 6 instead of 2 length).

To prevent that you can use `mb_strlen($string)` or change the `–`, with an `-`.

I would recommend using the `mb_` variant, so you are not only safe for the future, but also don't remove possible Typo`s (if this "dash" is actually the correct dash.. there are so many https://typefacts.com will help you a lot if this is in your interest).

Comment: Well... ['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) and ['EN DASH' (U+2013)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) are of course just different characters but you can't say how many bytes they use unless you choose an encoding. In UTF-16 they're both 2-byte chars. You'll also won't get the same output as in `String.length` for newest Unicode character that won't fit in original 2-byte UTF-16 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Your two versions are unlikely to print the same output because they do different things.

[JavaScript's `String.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) returns a character count (though based in an early and outdated definition of character):

```js
console.log(`–`.length);
console.log(``.length);
```

[PHP's `strlen()` function](http://php.net/strlen) returns a byte count and you're possibly using a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8 (or you should). Please compare:

```
var_dump(strlen('–'), mb_strlen('–'));
var_dump(strlen(''), mb_strlen(''));
```

```
int(3)
int(1)
int(4)
int(1)
```

You're also removing leading and trailing whitespace only in the JavaScript version and spaces are people too.

---

To build a reliable character-count cross-language function:

- PHP: [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/mb_strlen) should work fine out of the box, as long as you configure your application to tell PHP about encoding being used (or specify the encoding manually every time) and you feed it with properly encoded data. In 2018 there's normally no reason to use anything else than UTF-8.

  ```
  var_dump(mb_strlen('–', 'UTF-8'));
  ```
- JavaScript: [String.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) may seem to work for you if you think you don't need to account for emojis but, to be on the safe side, you can check [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) for some workarounds (the article is interesting even for pure learning purposes).

Comment: So how to validate text limit using JS that will be the same for PHP?

Comment: Use the same count algorithm. It's like comparing distances: you can use kilometres or miles, you can consider round trip or just one-way... but you cannot mix them.

Answer (score 0):

Ascii characters are 1 byte in length. strlen function assumes that every character is 1 byte in length, which works fine for the English language.

But when you start dealing with non-English languages, characters can take more than 1 byte to represent. If more than 1 byte should use mb_strlen.

Answer (score -1):

When i try to approximate **strlen** with JS i'm using :

```php
<?php
echo strlen("as%20"); // 13
```

```js
const str = "as%20"
const len = new URL(str.replace(/%[A-F0-9]{2}/g, "..."), "https:$").pathname.replace(/%[A-F0-9]{2}/g, ".").length - 1
console.log(len) // 13
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue,
js string length is different

```
var string = "adsf dsfkslk sldkflak fkddfsl ldafldskjf";
console.log(string.length);
```

php is giving different length

```
$string =  "adsf dsfkslk sldkflak fkddfsl ldafldskjf";
```

then I tried in php

```
 $my_str =  "adsf dsfkslk sldkflak fkddfsl ldafldskjf";
        $my_str = strip_tags($my_str);
        $my_str = html_entity_decode($my_str);
        $my_str = trim($my_str," \t\n\r\0\x0B\xC2\xA0");
        $my_str=trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $my_str));
        $my_str = mb_strlen($my_str);
```

it is returning the exact the count.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert line breaks in PHP because, in JavaScript, a line break is a single newline character. When it is sent, there are two that's why the count is not matching.

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
$description = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $description);
$description = str_replace("\r", "\n", $description);

$count = mb_strlen($description); // now this count will match with JavaScript var.length
```